Существительное от совершенных глаголов
Толька сейчас обнаружил, что существительные образуются только от несовершенных глаголов.
Сидеть-Сидение, Ходить - Хождение, ...

А вот с совершенными глаголами, как-то туго идет:
Посидеть -?
Полететь -?
Подойти - ?

Существуют ли отглагольные существительные совершенного вида на конвейерной основе? (то есть пару исключений не будет считаться)

Ну типа совершенный глагол, это действие которого закончилось, а существительные таки являются таковыми, потому что связаны с глаголами состояния, то есть с длящимися действиями. Было бы странно, если бы такие были, хотя есть существительные от глаголов прошедшего времени: сидел - сиделец.

Ну а в настоящем времени как будет сиделец? У нас похоже еще одна закономерность получается, что не существует сидельцев в настоящем времени.

Еще есть разные существительные. Глагол + ение, это основная конструкций, но наверное есть куча других конструкций, сколько? Приходить - Приход, Улетать - улет, улетание. И в чем разница между схемами?

Тоже "сиделец" будет, хоть в настоящем, хоть в прошедшем, хоть в будущем. Фишка, что прошедшее> настоящего и будущего вместе взятых, так как любое настоящее и будущее станет прошедшим.

Формирование слов «на конвейерной основе» характерно для искусственных языков. Для живых языков характерны именно исключения.

С этим не согласен. Вся грамматика это про закономерности, а исключения лишь соус поверх закономерностей.

Посидеть - посиделки. Полететь - полет. Подойти - найти подход к решению несуществующей проблемы...

Рассуждаем так:

Глаголы несовершенного вида

Рисовать, мечтать (несов. вид, процесс) — рисование, мечтание.
Рисовать, мечтать, писать (несов. вид, результат/предмет) — рисунок, мечта, письмо.

Глаголы совершенного вида:

Полететь, кончить, окончить (сов. вид, результат/предмет) — полет, конец, окончание.
Вывод
От глаголов несовершенного вида можно образовать существительные со значением названия действия (процесса) и результата действия (предмета), а от от глаголов совершенного вида — только существительные со значением  результата действия (предмета).
Это общая тенденция, исключения возможны.

Не совсем так. Есть 2 вида глаголов: Подать, Подавать. И механизмов образования существительных тоже должно быть минимум 2: пОдать, подаяние. Понятно, что Кончание нет такого слова, но механизм все таки есть, так что потенциально слово тоже есть. В итоге получаем те самые минимум 2 слова: Кончание и Конец. А вообще надо полистать монографии по связям существительных и глаголов, там небось целые иерархии.

Полистать, конечно, можно, но интереснее самим подумать. Глаголы делятся на два класса, обозначая завершенность или незавершенность действия. Логично предположить,  что образованные от них существительные также можно разделить на две разные группы.  И действительно,разница есть. От глаголов НСВ можно образовать сущ. со значением действия и предмета, а от глаголов СВ только предмета. Подаяние - это предмет от подать, а действие подавание  от подавать. Окончание - тоже предмет от окончить, конец  - предмет от кончить.  Посиделки, полет - предметы,  Но полет как движение/действие от лететь.

Сиделец - предмет от сидеть. Есть разные схемы словообразования, но суть именно такая. Улететь - улет, предмет. Улетать - улетание, действие. Вы начинаете обсуждать схемы, но от принципиальной разницы уходите, поэтому я вообще не понимаю вашего разговора и смысла самого ответа.

Забудьте вы уже про корни -лет- -бег- -ход- итп. Там по два глагола каждого вида - Лететь, Летать, Полететь, Полетать итд. Они не подходят для иллюстраций

Ну в целом согласен, примерно так и получается - процесс и результат. Но много нюансов, схем и часто результат отсутствует (например зашипеть, какой результат?). А у построить сразу и процесс и результат - Постройка\Построение. А так да -Подавать\Подать - Подача\подать\подавание\подаяние. Мыть/Помыть-Мытье\помыв. сгорать/сгореть - сгорание/???. стекать\стечь - стекание\стёк. Шипеть\Зашипеть - Шипение???
